# Java Timer Usage

Tags: java, timer

Hi I am using a timer for 2 tasks, which will monitor a set of IP address

```
public input ()
{

timer.schedule(task, 0, 8);
timer_second.schedule(task_monitor, 0, 5);
}
```

and I have 2 Timer Task

```
private final TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           }
}

private final TimerTask task2 = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           }
}
```

But as per my code logic, input () can be called more than one time , and if i call second time i get IllegalStateException: Task already scheduled or cancelled

Which seems to be obvious, but my logic is input can be called by different IP's and i have to monitor all such IP's using the 2 Timer Task

How should I avoid This ??
Please Help !!!!! 
Thanks in advance

Comment: either use a new task each time you call input, or pass new parameters to your task when you call input again

Comment: I believe that you cannot reuse the tasks concurrently across multiple timers.  You can use a task for exactly 0 or 1 timers at any given time.  This means that you need two new tasks each time you call input().